# Edit and add content in existing table of word document footer

Tags: excel, vba, ms-word, footer

I have a Word Doc with an existing header and footer. Inside of footer there is a table with info in some cells. I would like to know the Excel VBA code that edit and add more content in the footer table (update info of cells or add info in empty cells for example). The big problem I'm facing is I don't know how to make reference to cells positions inside footer table.

[image]

I'm working with Office 2013 and tried following approaches:

```
- wDoc.Sections(1).Footers(wdHeaderFooterPrimary)

- wDoc.ActiveWindow.ActivePane.View.SeekView = wdSeekCurrentPageFooter

-   Set rngFooter = wDoc.Sections(1).Footers(wdHeaderFooterPrimary).Range
    With rngFooter
        .ParagraphFormat.Alignment = 1
        .Text = "Some text"
        .Move Unit:=wdColumn, Count:=1
        .Text = "More Text at center: hyperlink"
        .Move Unit:=wdColumn, Count:=1
        .Text = "Page 1 of 1"
        .Move Unit:=wdRow, Count:=1
        .Text = "New Text in empty cell"
        With .Font
          .Size = 9
          .Name = "Arial Narrow"
        End With
    End With

- wDoc.Sections(1).Footers.Select
```

In case of third approach I get the following:

Footer result of third approach code

[image]

Comment: Cindy, thank you very much for your answer. I like your suggestion and I think objects structure is the elegant way to achieve the goal. However I posted an answer for my question that worked pretty well for me. Please let me know your thoughts about it. Thanks.

Comment: (Pease remember to "ping" using @UserName in order to ensure someone sees a reply) Your approach is also fine for solving your overall problem. The *stated requirement* in the question is: "The big problem I'm facing is I don't know how to make reference to cells positions inside footer table. " And that was what I was addressing in my Answer.

Answer (score 0):

In order to access a table's cells in a document footer a `Table` object is required. From there, the individual cells can be access via their cell index values. The code sample below assumes that the content of the cells should be *replaced*, not appended to.

Note: More correctly the formatting for an entire footer should not be applied directly. Instead, the definition of the Footer *style* should be changed.

```
Dim rngFooter as Word.Range
Dim tbl as Word.Table
Dim rngCell as Word.Range

    Set rngFooter = wDoc.Sections(1).Footers(wdHeaderFooterPrimary).Range
    With rngFooter
        Set tbl = rngFooter.Tables(1)
        SEt rngCell = tbl.Cell(1,1).Range
        With rngCell
          .ParagraphFormat.Alignment = 1
          .Text = "Some text"
        End With
        Set rngCell = tbl.Cell(1,2).Range
        rngCell.Text = "More Text at center: hyperlink"

        Set rngCell = tbl.Cell(1,3).Range
        rngCell.Text = "Page 1 of 1"

        With .Font
          .Size = 9
          .Name = "Arial Narrow"
        End With
    End With
```

Answer (score 0):

I found the following approach that solves my original problem:

```
    'Create a range from bookmark inside table cell
    Set firstRng = wDoc.Bookmarks("FirstCell").Range

    'Add or replace text in range created
    firstRng.Text = "Some text"

    'Create again the bookmark. It was deleted on the previous line 
    wDoc.Bookmarks.Add "FirstCell", firstRng

    Set secondRng = wDoc.Bookmarks("SecondCell").Range
    secondRng.Text = "More Text at center: hiperlink"
    wDoc.Bookmarks.Add "SecondCell", secondRng

    Set thirdRng = wDoc.Bookmarks("ThirdCell").Range
    thirdRng.Text = "Page 1 of 1"
    wDoc.Bookmarks.Add "ThirdCell", thirdRng

    Set fourthRng = wDoc.Bookmarks("FourCell").Range
    fourthRng.Text = "New Text in empty cell"
    wDoc.Bookmarks.Add "FourCell", fourthRng

    Set fifthRng = wDoc.Bookmarks("FifthCell").Range
    fifthRng.Text = "More New Text in empty cell"
    wDoc.Bookmarks.Add "FifthCell", fifthRng
```

[Footer Table after run code.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Y3eOf.png)

For the above code to work, it's necessary to create the bookmarks previously in the Word Document.

Moreover this method works to edit a Word Document at any position of any section in the file.